# Is there a convention for BEM to distinguishing state selectors from sub-class selectors?

Tags: html, css, bem

An example of sub-classing:

```
<button class="button button--large">
```

An example of state:

```
<button class="button button--open">
```

The two are meaningfully different. However, I couldn't find any BEM convention, that would make a distinction, they would both be written as modifiers.

I know other methodologies that might do something like this for state:

```
<button class="button is-open">
```

or

```
<button class="button is-button-open">
```

Comment: I would just go with `button button--active` rather than open, the button isn't open, but it's active when something is open - if that makes sense

Comment: @AndyHolmes I would visualize an Inactive button in such a way that pressing it would be pointless, since it is inactive. The dictionary definition of inactive is "doing nothing", but since the button is waiting to be clicked in both states, in both states it is equally busy. In neither state would I say the button is less active. This is why I think a name like open is better.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but the button itself isnt open, whatever it's affecting is. Buttons are inactive by default, which is why they have an `:active` state when clicked. I think you're thinking too deep into the definition of the word active

Comment: @AndyHolmes I think it makes actually more sense to think of the thing the button controls as inactive by default in case it is inaccessible, and the button as the activator. It makes no sense to activate the activator. I think of :active rather as the process of clicking, and this is also how :active works, it does not refer to the state after the clicking is over. In html, that state is :focus. The button itself doesn't even have to be open, we can think of a component state as open, where the button responds to this open state.

Comment: Buttons are inactive by default, I don't know what else to tell you. They're only active when they've been interacted with. Focus is when an element has focus, active is when the element is in the process of being clicked - they aren't the same thing. Honestly, I think you're going down a long and confusing road when the HTML spec outlines all of this super clearly.

Comment: @AndyHolmes If you read what I wrote, you can see I am pointing out the difference between focus and active, which means I understand they aren't the same thing. Again, :acitve does not refer to a state we usually mean with a class like ".button--active". :focus would be closer to what ".button--active" means. Therefore even if we look at the HTML specification, there is a more appropriate term (focus) we could adopt - even though we don't have to, since a class name can be whatever we believe is more descriptive.

Comment: "Buttons are inactive by default, they're only active when they've been interacted with." - This is incorrect, since :active does not refer to the state after the interaction.

Comment: "The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active 

Suggest you do a little more reading before you call things incorrect

Comment: It's semantics at the end of the day. I'm saying a button isn't open, a button element cannot be open, classes should actively describe what is going on. If your button opens a menu then yes you can do `button menu-open` but it just depends on your setup and whether you really need to think this deeply about it

Comment: Also further up you said "I would visualize an Inactive button in such a way that pressing it would be pointless, since it is inactive" - this isn't right, that's disabled. inactive != disabled/pointless. Buttons exist in an inactive state by default, if you tab to it on your keyboard it has focus, if you click/interact with it it is active. Simple.

Comment: @AndyHolmes What you are quoting is  exactly what I am trying to explain. Activation refers to the state WHILE pressing the button, but that is NOT what we mean with a selector like ".button--active",  which refers to the state AFTER pressing the button. Again, according to the docs, "focus" would be a more appropriate name. If you want to style a button after it has been clicked, you can't do it with :active, but you can do it with :focus.

Comment: @AndyHolmes According to how :active works, AFTER the click, the button would be INACTIVE again, but you suggest to style this state with ".button--active", which is confusing. So again, if you wanted to have a docs-inspired class name for the state AFTER the click, it should be ".button--foucused", not ".button--active", because again, after the click, the button is INACTIVE according to the docs.

Comment: As I said earlier, semantics. You have a good answer now :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes If you think it is semantics, why did you bring it up. :) :active does not describe the state after the click, that is what :focus does, this isn't semantics, this is how things are defined in the docs.

Comment: It's all good dude, just a good discussion. I can't really add any more to it, I don't really fancy dragging the points out, I'm not disagreeing with you any more and you've got a good answer so if it's all good with you I'd like to leave this as it is as you've made good points :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes Ok, I appreciate your input, thanks for having the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official rule in BEM for the state modifiers.

But… BEM has been largely influenced by the methodolgies the developers used before, like SMACSS for example. SMACSS has a guideline on how to write [state classes](http://smacss.com/book/type-state), and in your case it would be `.is-open`.

The developers I know write the state classes in BEM by folowing this pattern: `.[block]--is-[state]`.

It's still a valid BEM modifier class, and it's easily differentiable from modifiers used for static style composition.